# PHP attachment in email is empty

Tags: php, mysql, excel, email, csv

Im trying to take data from the database and display it in a CSV file which is both downloadable and emailed to someone. I have managed to get the downloadable file working and it displays all of the correct data. It also sends a CSV file to the necessary person but that CSV file is empty and no data is displayed in it.

Here is my code:

```
    $myroot = "../../";
    include($myroot . "inc/functions.php");
        // output headers so that the file is downloaded rather than displayed
        header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=surveys.csv');
        $output = fopen('php://output', 'w');
// Create CSV file
fputcsv($output, array('Name', 'Branch', 'Website','Company', 'Question1', 'Question2', 'Question3', 'Question4', 'Question5'));

$mysql_connection = db_connect_enhanced('*****','*****','*****','*****');
$query='SELECT * FROM *****.*****';
$surveys = db_query_into_array_enhanced($mysql_connection, $query);
$count = count($surveys);
$data = array();
    for($i=0; $i<=$count; $i++){
    $data[] = array($surveys[$i]['FeedbackName'], $surveys[$i]['BranchName'], $surveys[$i]['FeedbackWebsite'], $surveys[$i]['FeedbackCompany'], $surveys[$i]['Question1'], $surveys[$i]['Question2'], $surveys[$i]['Question3'], $surveys[$i]['Question4'], $surveys[$i]['Question5']);  
}

foreach( $data as $row )  
{  
    fputcsv($output, $row, ',', '"');  
}  
fclose($output);  

$encoded = chunk_split(base64_encode($output));

// create the email and send it off

$subject = "File you requested from RRWH.com";
$from = "*****@*****.com";
$headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\n";
$headers .= 'Content-Type: multipart/mixed;
   boundary="----=_NextPart_001_0011_1234ABCD.4321FDAC"' . "\n";

$message = '

This is a multi-part message in MIME format.

------=_NextPart_001_0011_1234ABCD.4321FDAC
Content-Type: text/plain;
       charset="us-ascii"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

Hello

We have attached for you the PHP script that you requested from http://rrwh.com/scripts.php
as a zip file.

Regards

------=_NextPart_001_0011_1234ABCD.4321FDAC
Content-Type: application/octet-stream;  name="';

$message .= "surveys.csv";
$message .= '"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="';
$message .= "surveys.csv";
$message .= '"

';
$message .= $encoded;
$message .= '

------=_NextPart_001_0011_1234ABCD.4321FDAC--

';
mail("*****@*****.com", $subject, $message, $headers, "-f$from");
```

I've spent a day and a half on this but I cant see the problem. Could someone please point it out to me as to why the attached CSV file is empty?

i'm getting kind of desperate and stressed out :( please someone help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would have helped you taking a look at your error logs or at least setting

```
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

as that would have told you that base64_encode expects a string but $output is a resource.

Try setting

```
ob_start();
```

to the beginning and

```
$output = ob_get_flush();
```

between your fclose & $encoded lines.

haven't tryed the mail yet but this should help you at least a bit :)

I tryed this code and everything worked well:

```
<?php
ob_start();
header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=surveys.csv');

$output = fopen('php://output', 'w');
fputcsv($output, array('Name', 'Branch', 'Website','Company', 'Question1', 'Question2', 'Question3', 'Question4', 'Question5'));
$data = array();
$data[] = array('Name', 'Branch', 'Website','Company', 'Question1', 'Question2', 'Question3', 'Question4', 'Question5');

foreach( $data as $row )
{
    fputcsv($output, $row, ',', '"');
}
fclose($output);

$output = ob_get_flush();

$encoded = chunk_split(base64_encode($output));
```

Comment: Hi, I am a rookie PHP developer and know very little. Where would I put the ini_set lines? I placed ob_start() and echo ($output = ob_get_flush()); where you instructed me too but now the downloadable CSV file is empty (it wasnt before) and the email no longer sends at all (it sent before but with an empty CSV file)

Comment: ini_set() has to be at the beginning of your script
furthermore it should last to write $output = ob_get_flush();

I've tested that code above and everything worked well